# stemming words , i'm facing error in my program

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using python, using this code to stem words but it's not working

```
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
stemmer = PorterStemmer()
stemmer.stem('cooking')
'cook'
```

Comment: What is not working? What is the error?

Comment: the code is not working it's not showing any output , i'm using python 3.7 , i guess i'm missing any library or syntax problem , but can't figure it out ???

Comment: You throw away the stemmed value .... what is your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is working. Just add a `print` in the end of the script:

```
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
stemmer = PorterStemmer()
result = stemmer.stem('cooking')
print(result)
```

Or copy-paste this code to a Jupyter notebook and run it there.

Comment: I think the OP knows about printing the result!